# Usando valor retornado em função para criar uma listview flutter

Tags: flutter

Tenho uma função que acessa o *Firestore* e retorna uma lista, quando clico em um botão essa função é chamada e deveria criar uma `lisrviwerbuilder()`. Mas não sei por que ele não cria.

```
    readdados() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('cliente').getDocuments();
    snapshot.documents.forEach((d) {listanomes.add(d.data['nome']);
    });
    return listanomes;
  }     
    RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                      readdados();
                    }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      itemCount: listanomes.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(title: Text(listanomes[index]));
                      })),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando um `StatefulWidget` modifique o clique do teu botão da seguinte forma:

```
readdados() async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('cliente').getDocuments();
    snapshot.documents.forEach((d) {listanomes.add(d.data['nome']);
  });

  return listanomes;
} 

RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() async{
        readdados();
      });
    }),
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      itemCount: listanomes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(listanomes[index]));
      })
),
```

**Explicação**

Utilizando o `setState((){})` você indica para o Flutter que ele deve redesenhar esse Widget, assim sua lista será alterada.

**Dica**

Como você está trabalhando com o *Firebase* você pode utilizar Streams para deixar seu app "automático", busque por `StreamBuilder` + Firebase.

*Obs.: Se isso não resolver seu problema, **Edite** sua pergunta e coloque mais informações, mais código seria perfeito.*